# How to get Screens DPI by Qt application in Linux framebuffer mode(without X11)

Tags: arm, qt5, screen, embedded-linux, dpi

Currently I am running Qt and QML application in Embedded Linux Built using buildroot. GUI comes up good in the screen. 
Application runs in framebuffer mode, X11 is not present in Linux.

I want to know the DPI of the screen in my application.

I used below Qt API to get DPI

```
qreal screenDPI = QApplication::primaryScreen()->physicalDotsPerInch();
qDebug() << "***************screenDPI***************" << screenDPI;
```

Output of the above is

```
***************screenDPI***************inf
```

It is not fetching the required DPI value.

Screen size 800*480.

Same API works good in Ubuntu Linux 18.04 and Windows.

**physicalDotsPerInch** is not working as expected.

Is there any alternative API that I can use to get DPI of the screen in *embedded Linux running in frame buffer mode*.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to get QApplication::primaryScreen()->physicalSize?
If so you could calculate the DPI yourself by using the geometry of your window.

What device are you using? what is the output of :
manufacturer 
model 
name

Comment: I know the physical size of screen and also DPI what manufacturer mentioned in specification. But what qt application is considering is not known. Wanted to cross check with what I got and what qt application is taking. I will check for  physicalSize and udpate

Comment: Take into account the Qt Docs mention that on certain devices the results yielded by Qt are not always correct. So it's always good practice to test these on your specific device.